# Can't access apache by port 80 from external

Tags: port, apache-2.4, xampp

I followed a lot of solutions I found, but it still doesn't work.
I can access the server by port 80 inside my network, bui I can't on another one, just by another port (like 62, as I set).

---

### Files:

#### httpd.conf

```
Listen localhost:80
Listen *my_ip*:80
Listen *my_ip*:62

...

ServerName *a_free_DNS*:80

...

#
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
#
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
```

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
```

```
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI 

    MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
```

```
</Directory>
```

#### httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName *a_free_DNS*
    DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/home/
</VirtualHost>
```

#### httpd-xampp.conf

```
#
# New XAMPP security concept
#
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
    #    Require local
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from localhost
    Allow from 192.168.0.*
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

I put here just what I thought is important and what was modified.

---

I'm using an Arris router. I set as following:

#### Virtual Servers:

```
Description     Inbound Port    Type    Private IP Address      Local Port
Server          20-81           TCP     192.168.0.123           20-81
```

#### Port Triggers

I tried

```
Description     Outbound Port   Type    Inbound Port
Server          80-80           TCP     62-62
```

and

```
Description     Outbound Port   Type    Inbound Port
Server          62-62           TCP     80-80
```

and

```
Description     Outbound Port   Type    Inbound Port
Server          20-81           TCP     20-81
```

and any.

I tried disable the router's firewall too. What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using port forwarding, instead of port triggering. Your web server is not making an initial connection which is what you need for port triggering. Also start by setting everything to one port instead of a range.

Comment: The router settings have no port forwarding option, just port triggering. Anyway, you was right about set one port instead of a range, it's working!!! xD Thanks

Comment: Isn't working anymore, and I didn't change anything. ='[

Comment: When I try to enter using the adress of the free DNS, the adress, at the adress bar of the browser, is changed to my.adress/cgi-bin/status_cgi

Comment: Try using only the virtual server, with one port and no port triggering.

Comment: Nothing... '__'

Comment: Could port 80 be used by the router for management? AS a test see if your server is responding to port 25 by doing "telnet 192.168.0.123 25" then setup your virtual server on port 25 and see if that works externally, using the public ip address of course.

Comment: I tested telnet, but it didn't work for port 25, so I put **192.168.0.123:25** on `Listen` and **_my_freeDNS_:25** on `ServerName` at `httpd.conf`, and setted the Virtual Server for port **25**, but it didn't work too, nor for internal connection (the port 80 works on internal connection). If I change the port to 62 on all this configurations, it works. So the server doesn't work on 80 externally and on 25 internally and externally.

Comment: The 25 was a test, so ignore it. I would say that your router is using port 80 for it's management. You should be able to change the management port to something else so it doesn't interfere.